# An efficient way to check when a specific LazyColumn item comes into view?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-compose-list

I need to check when a certain `LazyColumn` item comes into view, and once it does, make a callback to `onItemWithKeyViewed()` only once to notify that this item has been viewed.
My attempt:

```
@Composable
fun SpecialList(
    someItems: List<Things>,
    onItemWithKeyViewed: () -> Unit
) {
    val lazyListState = rememberLazyListState()

    if (lazyListState.isScrollInProgress) {
        val isItemWithKeyInView = lazyListState.layoutInfo
            .visibleItemsInfo
            .any { it.key == "specialKey" }
        if (isItemWithKeyInView) {
            onItemWithKeyViewed()
        }
    }

    LazyColumn(
        state = lazyListState
    ) {
        items(items = someItems) { itemData ->
            ComposableOfItem(itemData)
        }
        item(key = "specialKey") {
            SomeOtherComposable()
        }
    }
}
```

Issue with my method is I notice the list scrolling performance degrades badly and loses frames. I realize this may be because it's checking all visible item keys on every frame?

Also, `onItemWithKeyViewed()` is currently being called multiple times instead of just the first time it's viewed.

Is there a more efficient way to make a single callback to `onItemWithKeyViewed()` only the first time `"specialKey"` item is viewed?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

1. In such cases, when you have a state that is updated often, you should use [`derivedStateOf`](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/compose/runtime/package-summary#derivedStateOf(kotlin.Function0)): this will cause recomposition only when the result of the calculation actually changes.
2. You should not call side effects (which is calling `onItemWithKeyViewed`) directly in the composable builder. You should use one of the special side-effect functions instead, usually `LaunchedEffect` - this ensures that the action is not repeated. You can find more information on this topic in [Thinking in Compose](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/mental-model) and in side-effects [documentation](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/side-effects).

```kotlin
val isItemWithKeyInView by remember {
    derivedStateOf {
        lazyListState.isScrollInProgress &&
                lazyListState.layoutInfo
                    .visibleItemsInfo
                    .any { it.key == "specialKey" }
    }
}
if (isItemWithKeyInView) {
    LaunchedEffect(Unit) {
        onItemWithKeyViewed()
    }
}
```

Comment: I want to do some call when each list item becomes visible. But it should only be done once. Ideally, I would like to avoid calling the same function as you scroll up and down. What pattern can I follow? Secondly, what is the effect of LazyColumn's recreation/recomposition of the Composables? Are the effects restarted?